# Error coming while compiling C++ program using #include "DarkGDK.h"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to run the  C++ code but i am facing this error

```
Build started: Project: roman numerals, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Main.cpp
1>c:\users\owner\documents\dark gdk\projects\roman numerals\roman numerals\main.cpp(40) : error C2065: 'number' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\owner\documents\dark gdk\projects\roman numerals\roman numerals\main.cpp(40) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Owner\Documents\Dark GDK\Projects\roman numerals\roman numerals\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>roman numerals - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

*This is the code:*

```
#include "DarkGDK.h"
const int I = 1;
const int II = 2;
const int III = 3;
const int IV = 4;
const int V = 5;

void setup();
void input();
void display();
void cleanup();
void DarkGDK()
{
      setup();
      input();
      cleanup();
}
void setup()
{
       dbSetWindowOff();
       dbLoadBitmap("C:\\Users\\Owners\\Pictures\\DeVry\\roman numeral 1.bmp",I);
       dbLoadBitmap("C:\\Users\\Owners\\Pictures\\DeVry\\roman numeral 2.bmp",II);
       dbLoadBitmap("C:\\Users\\Owners\\Pictures\\DeVry\\roman numeral 3.bmp",III);
       dbLoadBitmap("C:\\Users\\Owners\\Pictures\\DeVry\\roamn numeral 4.bmp",IV);
       dbLoadBitmap("C:\\Users\\Owners\\Pictures\\DeVry\\roamn numeral 5.bmp",V);
}

void input()
{
       dbPrint("enter a number1 to 5 to see its roman numeral");
       int number = 0;
       number = atoi(dbInput());
       display();
}

void display ()
{
       while (number !=6)
       {
              switch (number)
              {
              case 1:
                   dbCopyBitmap(I,0);
                   break;
              case 2:
                   dbCopyBitmap(II,0);
                   break;
              case 3:
                   dbCopyBitmap(III,0);
                  break;
             case 4:
                  dbCopyBitmap(IV,0);
                 break;
             case 5:
                  dbCopyBitmap(V,0);
                  break;
             case 6:
                  dbPrint("ending program");
                  dbWait(2000);
             default:
                  dbPrint("not a valid choice, only numbers 1 through 5 work");
                 dbPrint("try again");
              }
       }
}

void cleanup ()
{
       dbDeleteImage(I);
       dbDeleteImage(II);
       dbDeleteImage(III);
       dbDeleteImage(IV);
       dbDeleteImage(V);
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message that tells you exactly what the problem is aren't you understanding? There is no `number`

Answer (score 3):

```
void input()
{
       dbPrint("enter a number1 to 5 to see its roman numeral");
       int number = 0;
       number = atoi(dbInput());
       display();
}

void display ()
{
       while (number !=6)
       {
        // ...
```

`display` function has no variable called `number` at it's scope to access. The scope of `number` is only in `input` function and cannot be propagated to function(s) it in turn calls.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to pass the `number` parameter to the `display` function.

```
        int number = 0;
        number = atoi(dbInput());
-       display();
+       display(number);
 }

-void display ()
+void display (int number)
 {
        while (number !=6)
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `number` variable in `display()` function. It is inaccessible here.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable 'number' inside the Input() function, meaning it will ONLY exist inside this function. You are trying to use it from another function (on line 40) and the compiler can't see it. What you need to do is place number outside of any functions at the top of your code (where the const int declerations are):

e.g

```
int number;

void input()
{
       dbPrint("enter a number1 to 5 to see its roman numeral");
       number = atoi(dbInput()); //Set the value of number here
       display();
}

void display ()
{
       while (number !=6) //use number here
       {
           ...
       }
}
```